# Usage of it and them with the same noun

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Here is an example situation where the noun refers to something in general-

(General statement) The coconut tree is my favourite tree. It can grow up to a height of 25 meters.

(1) I used to climb them and pick their fruits.

(2) Although it is so tall, I used to climb it and pick its fruits.

(3) Although it is so tall, I used to climb them and pick their fruits.

(4) Although they are so tall, I used to climb them and pick their fruits.

I feel (3) is awkward and am not sure about (2). Can someone give some input and maybe an explanation?

Comment: Your example sentences are not numbered or otherwise distinguished from your text. We can't tell which one is (3).

Comment: I have edited to clarify. Please check that I have done so correctly.

Comment: @Anton Yes, they are numbered correctly. I apologize for not writing it properly.

Comment: You climbed more than one coconut tree, so you need *they*. But *they* needs a plural antecedent: *I used to climb coconut trees...* or *Although coconut trees are so tall, I used to climb them...* or *Although they are so tall, I used to climb coconut trees...*

Comment: But when you're using a singular, can't you also interpret it as a group? I saw a text like this - I often mistook it(a plant) for...

Comment: You can use the singular to refer to a group but it is a special group consisting of all the individuals that are, ever have been and ever will be in existence. As soon as you start to define a subset of that group (for example "all the coconut trees in Trinidad") you have to use the plural no matter how big the subset is unless the subset contains only one individual (for example "When I lived in Trinidad there was a large coconut tree behind our house. When it had ripe fruit I would climb it to cut them down")..